# method being called multiple times when it should only be called once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

apologies for the nooby post, its my first time posting and am a beginner dev.
I am creating a 3d unity game of a prize wheel / wheel of fortune, and am having issues when trying to write the wheels controller script.
I am determining the prize based on the rotation angle of the wheel once its done spinning, and printing it to console. However, when i run the code, it prints the result 3x, with the last one being the correct one and the first 2 being incorrect. here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PrizeWheelController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform insideWheel;
    public float initialSpinSpeed = 1500.0f;
    public float minSpinDuration = 2.0f;
    public float maxSpinDuration = 5.0f;
    public float decelerationRate = 300.0f;
    public Button spinButton;

    private bool isSpinning = false;
    private bool prizeDetermined = false;
    private float spinSpeed;
    private float totalRotation = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        spinButton.onClick.AddListener(SpinWheel);
    }

    private IEnumerator SpinWheelRoutine()
    {
        isSpinning = true;
        prizeDetermined = false;
        spinButton.interactable = false;

        float spinDuration = Random.Range(minSpinDuration, maxSpinDuration);
        float spinTime = 0f;
        spinSpeed = initialSpinSpeed;
        totalRotation = 0f;

        while (spinTime < spinDuration)
        {
            spinTime += Time.deltaTime;
            spinSpeed = Mathf.Max(spinSpeed - decelerationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
            float rotationStep = spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            totalRotation += rotationStep;
            insideWheel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(totalRotation, 0f, 0f);
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f); // Wait for 5 seconds after the wheel has stopped

        if (!prizeDetermined)
        {
            DetermineAndDisplayPrize();
            prizeDetermined = true;
        }

        isSpinning = false;
        spinButton.interactable = true;
    }

    public void SpinWheel()
    {
        if (!isSpinning)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpinWheelRoutine());
        }
    }

    private void DetermineAndDisplayPrize()
    {
        float finalRotation = NormalizeAngle(totalRotation);
        string prize = DeterminePrize(finalRotation);
        Debug.Log("Final Rotation: " + finalRotation);
        Debug.Log("Prize won: " + prize);
    }

    private float NormalizeAngle(float angle)
    {
        return (angle % 360 + 360) % 360;
    }

    private string DeterminePrize(float angle)
    {
        if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 45) return "$0";
        if (angle >= 46 && angle <= 90) return "$1000";
        if (angle >= 91 && angle <= 135) return "$600";
        if (angle >= 136 && angle <= 180) return "$400";
        if (angle >= 181 && angle <= 225) return "3x";
        if (angle >= 226 && angle <= 270) return "$800";
        if (angle >= 271 && angle <= 315) return "$200";
        if (angle >= 316 && angle < 360) return "2x";

        return "Unknown Prize";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine.  Double check that there aren't multiple prize wheel controllers in the scene.

Comment: youre a genius omg, im so dumb, ty xD